# Notepad++ disable document tab undocking

Tags: notepad++

I have had a little look around for the answer for this, but not too sure if I'm using the correct wording :/

Basically, my little sister is using notepad++ to learn some coding, and she has butter fingers, so keeps un-docking the documents. This causes like 17 different notepad++ windows to be open.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Lock (no drag and drop)` tab Option under `Preferences-> General.`

[image]

You will not be able to drag your tab bar to rearrange, and this will limit you from dragging it out of the parent window to create a new notepad++ window.

Comment: Cool, cheers, I'll give it a go when I get back home :D

Comment: `Preferences` is under `Settings` for `Settings > Preferences`